# Textbook for analysis in Euclidean spaces

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, book-recommendation

I am finding some nice text book for analysis in high dimensional real spaces which can provide rigorous definition and  proofs. I am taking real analysis and complex analysis. I saw something like total derivative and Jacobian matrix as the introductory material in the textbook Complex analysis by E.stein to compare the holomorphic function and the "differentiable" functions. But I do not have knowledge about total derivative things, since I was not interested in them when I was taking calculus courses. But I am now interested in them, are there some nice text books which can provide nice and rigorous treatment about those knowledge? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I like "Advanced Calculus" by Fitzpatrick, which starts from the beginning (the axioms of the real numbers). It does all of one-variable calculus first, and in the second half of the book it gets to the multivariable things that you are interested in.

Comment: Others will probably cite numerous modern books, but for a relatively brief and extremely rigorous and informed treatment, see [**Calculus of Several Variables**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0063561859) by Casper Goffman. Also, see [**Analysis in Euclidean Space**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486458040) by Kenneth Hoffman (the "Hoffman" of the very well-known linear algebra text), which was the text for an advanced undergraduate course I had in Fall 1977 (it was designed to follow a 2-semester advanced calculus course). And [this book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486683362) by C. H. Edwards

Comment: thank you very much.